# How to add data to the array of hash map in the document using Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I want to add data to the existing array without overwriting. And inside each document, I have an array of `HashMap`. I am trying to add data to the existing one. Kindly check the below code and shed some light.

```
   public void createNewCase(){
     Map<String, String> caseInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();


    caseInfo.put("chief_complaint", chiefComplaintET.getText().toString());
        caseInfo.put("facility", facilityET.getText().toString());
        caseInfo.put("location", locationET.getText().toString());
        caseInfo.put("assigned_provider", assignProviderET.getText().toString());
        caseInfo.put("referring_provider", referringProviderET.getText().toString());
        caseInfo.put("admit_date", adminDateET.getText().toString());
        caseDictionary.add(caseInfo);
        final String patientID = sharedPrefHelper.getStr("patient_id");



        db.collection("patients").whereEqualTo("patient_id", patientID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            private static final String TAG = "New Case Creation" ;

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        patient patient = new patient();
                        list = (List) document.get("patient_case");
                        for (HashMap<String, String> item:list) {
                            caseDictionary.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(caseDictionary);
                    HashMap<String, Object> uploadData = new HashMap<>();
                    uploadData.put("patient_case", caseDictionary);
                    DocumentReference caseRef = db.collection("patients").document(patientID); // am stuck here

                }else{
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(NewCase.this, "Something bad happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Helper.m_Dialog.hide();
                }

            }
        });

}
```

**Edit 1**
   Below code deleting old data and adding new data. I need to append.

```
   final String patientID = sharedPrefHelper.getStr("patient_id");
        final CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection("patients");
    collectionReference.whereEqualTo("patient_id", patientID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            Toast.makeText(NewCase.this, task.getResult().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                    Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("patient_case", caseInfo);

                    collectionReference.document(document.getId()).set(map, SetOptions.merge());
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(NewCase.this, task.getResult().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your screenshot, in your `patients` collection you have documents that contain an array that holds maps (objects). In order to be able to update those maps that exist within your array you should create a `Map` object that corresponde to your exact document structure and use DocumentReference's [set(Object data, SetOptions options)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html) method for that. So pass as the first argument the map and as the second argument `SetOptions.merge()`. You can find a simpler example in my answer from the following post:

- [Firestore firebase Android search and update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378868/firestore-firebase-android-search-and-update-query)

Comment: I was on vacation. I am going to try today and will update you. For more clarity, let me tell you my scenario again, am having an array of hash maps, every time when I add data, it should append to array of hash maps. Can you please edit my code?

Comment: Yes, an arrays of hash maps, it's correct. Ok, give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Ok. where to mention the patient_case field?

Comment: If you started to make your own attempt for solving this issue using the information provided in my answer, please consider ask another question if something else comes up. I cannot guide at every step in your development.

Comment: dude it's a same question. you have used document.getId() in your example, in my case I need to append data to the particular field. Your example doesn't show that.

Comment: Hi Alex. I can able to add data, but it's not appending. It's deleting the existing maps in the array and adding the new map. I have edited the code.

Comment: @Mac_Play Call `set()` and pass as the first argument the map and as the second argument `SetOptions.merge()`, so you can update the document and not overwrite it, right? Do it this way and tell me if it works.

Comment: I have edited the original question by adding new code. I have done the same way as you mentioned in the last text. But it's not appending, For example I have two maps in array already, when I add new data, it's removing the existing two data and adding the new data.

Comment: You provided incomplete data. I cannot see any `patient_id` property in your database. Beside that, you aren't following recommenedations in my answer at all. You map doesn't have the same structure as your document. The `patient_case` property is actually a list of maps. If it would be easy for you, get the entire document, get the list of maps, add/remove data and write the document back.

Comment: @Mac_Play That's why I have asked you earlier, to make your own attempt and if you find hard times in solving it, post another fresh question using an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so me or other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Done @Alex Mamo

Answer (score 0):

- This is one of my example
- i have done it like this

  ```
   List<Map> history = List();  

   History historyObj = History(typee, name, timeStamp, pointsBefore, points, itemPoints);  

   history.add(historyObj.toMap());  

   //Firesore collection object  

   CollectionReference child = _firestore.collection('children');  

   //Firesore document object  

   DocumentReference docRef = child.doc(selectedChild.childId);  

   // "history" is your "patient_case"  

   docRef.update({"history": FieldValue.arrayUnion(history)}).then(
       (value) => print("Update done"));
  ```
- History is one of my class
- History class includes method toMap() which converts all history class variables and its values to 'Key' : 'value' form like this

  ```
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {  
       "type": type,
       "name": name,
       "timestamp": timestamp,
       "points_before": points_before,
       "points_after": points_after,
       "points_affected": points_affected,
     };
  ```